# OCMockito get count of invocations on mock

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmockito

How can one get the count of invocations on a mocked object?

At a particular point in a test I'd like to get the current count of invocations for a certain method, then continue the test and finally validate that the method was invoked one more time.

This would be something like:

```
[given([mockA interestingMethod]) willReturnInt:5];
<do some work that may call 'interestingMethod' one or two times>
NSInteger count = currentCountOfInvocations([mockA interestingMethod]); //or something similar
<do some more work that [hopefully] calls interesting method one more time>
[verifyCount(mockA, times(count + 1)) interestingMethod];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock anything with a block. So let's use a block to increment our own counter.

```
__block NSUInteger interestingMethodCount = 0;
[given([mockA interestingMethod]) willDo:^id(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    interestingMethodCount += 1;
    return @5;
}];

<do some work that may call 'interestingMethod' one or two times>
NSUInteger countAtCheckpoint = interestingMethodCount;

<do some more work that [hopefully] calls 'interestingMethod' one more time>
assertThat(@(interestingMethodCount), is(equalTo(@(countAtCheckpoint + 1))));
```